# Word wrap in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, word-wrap

I cannot figure out how to get the HTML elements to wrap lines in Chrome dev tools. I'm working with some long and complicated SVG paths and I hate scrolling horizontally to check the other element attributes. Word wrap is checked under the settings area in chrome dev tools. Suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's possible now, check my updated answer

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Looks like there is no Word Wrap available for now :( and seems like people have been asking forever, I just posted my vote for word wrap too

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=73193

**Edit: looks like it is a feature by default now (click on the three dots on the top right, then click on Settings):**

[image]

Comment: Still no word wrap for the "Network" tab when viewing "Response". :(

Comment: Cheers.. I was looking for the option to disable wrapping!

Answer (score 13):

This is quite an old thread, but unfortunately still relevant.

Word wrap only works in the **Elements** panel. From the documentation:

> As with any text editor you can choose to wrap long lines of code in the Elements panel.

The link in Leon's answer actually refers to the Network panel, although several of the comments suggest that others are also looking at this more generally; e.g.

> It would be good if wordwrap is offered for all content.

and ...

> I would donate my left kidney for word wrap!

Anyway, if you're mainly editing html, you're in luck - just use the Elements panel instead of the Sources panel. Unfortunately, most of my editing is with JS.

So I'll open a new issue in Chromium and post a link back here, in case anyone wants to support it.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Annoying

Comment: There is now a feature in `Sources` tab to "pretty-print" (`Format`) the content of the tab:  **click the icon that looks like `{ }` in the bottom left of the `Sources` tab**.  (There is sometimes a notification that comes up to mention this feature, but not sure how to trigger that.)

Comment: @TT-- Thanks for your tip!  

The same "pretty-print" is also available in the **Network** tab when selecting a file on the left and reviewing its **Response** on the right. Just look for the ```{ }``` in the bottom left corner.

Answer (score 3):

The { } in the footer while on the Network > Response tab worked beautifully to wrap my HTML.\KimBley

Comment: this doesn't wrap anything at all, it only formats the JSON

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome's [Issue 167287: Feature request: word wrap for sources panel](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=167287), developers said:

**[Oct 13, 2014]**

> We depend heavily here on codemirror capabilities.
>
> ---
>
> Upstream bug: https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/1356

and:

**[Dec 14, 2017]**

> I am a bit scared of the performance concerns of this. Will revisit when we have a more performant way of displaying large/minified files. [**Status**: Assigned → WontFix]

However, the actual work to fix that CodeMirror issue was broken down into two pieces, each with it's own bug:

- <s>[Split measuring of long/huge lines – Issue #1022](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/1022)</s> (Closed on Jan 27, 2014)
- [Experiment with a partial algorithm for redrawing lines – Issue #2090](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/2090) (still open, but sounds as though it applies regardless of word-wrap?)

So, they're worried that wrapping super-long lines would grind the editor to a halt. If you can convince them otherwise, with or without actually improving CodeMirror, they would *probably* be willing to add an option for wrapping in the Sources tab.

So go mess around with:

- https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror
- https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend

Answer (score 1):

I captured a screenshot just for clarify the "Pretty Print" option at the bottom!

[image]